# Changing Threshold in confusion matrix Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, confusion-matrix

Given I have true label values and predicted values, and calculated optimal threshold, how do I construct a confusion matrix using that optimal threshold?

```
# given data 
label = np.array([0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1])
pred = np.array([0.15,0.2,0.25,0.37,0.41,0.55,0.65,0.8,0.92,0.99])

fpr, tpr, thresh = metrics.roc_curve(label, pred)
auc = metrics.roc_auc_score(label, pred)

# Getting optimal threshold 
def optimal_index (tpr, fpr, thresh ):
    optimal_idx = np.argmax(tpr - fpr)
    optimal_thres = thresh[optimal_idx]
    return optimal_thres
    

threshold = optimal_index(tpr, fpr, thresh)

print("Optimal Threshold value for Classifier  is :", threshold_1)
Optimal Threshold value for Classifier is : 0.8
```

Now I need to construct a confusion matrix using that 0.8 optimal threshold, but I simply can't figure out how to achieve that.
Please provide any insight! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use `metrics.confusion_matrix`, method

```py
matrix = metrics.confusion_matrix(label, y_pred)
disp = metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=matrix, display_labels=[0, 1])
disp.plot()
plt.show()
```

convert pred score list to label for your optimum theshold

```
y_pred = list(map(lambda x : 0 if x < threshold else 1, pred))
```

For more help visit [plot confusion matrix with keras](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html)